# In CSS how to achieve, two cells with auto width in fixed width parent, with priority to see content in second cell and with ellipsis at first cell?

Tags: html, css

I want to have address and number in same line. For example in 400px parent div. But if address + number exceed 400px length I want to add ellipsis for address and show number without crop.

My code is here, but I did only fixed width for number. I want auto width for this number to not make much space between address and number if number is too short.

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</td>
            <td style="width:35px;">1234</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

div.container {
    width:400px;
    border:dashed 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/ArfUA/3/

Comment: is replacing table and using a fluid layout with divs acceptable?

Comment: please send me an example.

Comment: @huh I posted an example in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you set `float:right` to the element which you always want to be visible and you

set `display:block` to the other element with the ellipsis.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ArfUA/10/)**

[image]

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="short">1234</span>
    <span class="long ellipsis">LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongWord</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    width:400px;
    border:dashed 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.short {
    float: right;
    background: yellow; /*just for demo; */
}
.long
{
    display: block;
    background: pink; /*just for demo; */
}
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ellipsis addname">LongLongLongLoLongLongLongLoLongLongLongLoLongLongLongLoLongLongLongLo</div>
            <div class="addnum">1234</div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.container {
    width:400px;
    border:dashed 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.addname{
    max-width:90%;
}
.addnum{
    max-width:10%;
    /*margin-left:-2px;*/
}

.addname,.addnum{
    float:left;
}
.container{
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ArfUA/5/

Comment: I need to see whole number. For example, when I wrote 10 digit number it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content contained in the mark-up is not tabular data. Fix this by using DIVs instead and then have the CSS apply:

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column address">[long text]
    </div>
    <div class="column text">[short text]
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* clears floats */
    width: 400px
}
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
.text {
    width: 35px
}
```

Now, w/ the different columns can be differentiated using the second css class.